# nested packages?

Tags: ros, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I create nested packages in ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190270/nested-packages?/) by [Arun](https://answers.ros.org/users/19860/arun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can create a [metapackage](http://wiki.ros.org/Metapackages).

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2